# ASP.net c# Sorting a data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, data-access-layer

I'm using DAL, and having trouble figuring out how to sort the returned data table.  The case is throwing an error and intellisense isn't offering me much help:

```
// Get all the specifications available to this user
Artwork.tblSpecificationsDataTable dsCommon = new Artwork.tblSpecificationsDataTable();            
 using (tblSpecificationsTableAdapter specAdapter = new tblSpecificationsTableAdapter())
 {
  specAdapter.FillByClientID(dsCommon, Master.loginData.loggedInUser.company.ID);
  }

 DataView v = dsCommon.DefaultView;
 v.Sort = "category DESC";
 dsCommon = (Artwork.tblSpecificationsDataTable)v.ToTable();

 for (int i = 0; i < dsCommon.Count; i++)
  {
   test.Text += dsCommon[i].category + " " + dsCommon[i].FlatSize + "<br />";
  }
```

Error without the cast is:

> Error 3   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Data.DataTable' to
>   'Artwork.tblSpecificationsDataTable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

**Edit**

Apparently I should be sorting in the query which is fine, but I want the option to ORDER BY any of the dozen fields without having to create a dozen queries in the table adapter, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Why are you not sorting in the database?

Comment: I have a table adapter that fetches the rows, I want to return the rows in different ways, lots of sort methods but without having to have a seperate query for each one.  Is this the wrong way to go about that?

Comment: my answer to the question "what's the best sort method?" is always "the ORDER BY clause in T-SQL". If your client-to-server connectivity is slow, then it makes some sense to download rows once and then sort them in various ways in the client code. Otherwise, it's easiest to let the DB do your sorting.

Comment: @Musi How do I sort the rows without having to have dozens of similar queries in the table adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessarily correct to to say that the database will perform the sort faster than the client - in *most* cases this statement is true, but you would have to look at the query plan in SQL Server to see if it genuinely would be quicker.

You can write a query like this, which allows dynamic sorting in the table adapter...

```
SELECT
    <field list>
FROM
    <TableName>
WHERE
    <Clause>
ORDER BY
CASE @OrderBy
    WHEN 'Field1' THEN Field1
    WHEN 'Field2' THEN Field2
    WHEN 'Field3' THEN Field3
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a guess. According to [MSDN,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f.aspx) `DataView.ToTable()` returns a new `DataTable`. But you are passing that to an existing variable `dsCommon.`

There is a very similar [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.table.aspx) `DataView.Table` that gets or sets the source `DataTable` behind the `DataView`.

Does your problem go away if you change the line

```
dsCommon = (Artwork.tblSpecificationsDataTable)v.ToTable();
```

to

```
dsCommon = (Artwork.tblSpecificationsDataTable)v.Table();
```

Comment: Doesn't throw an error but data still not coming up in any particular order.

Comment: Can you use the sorted DataView instead of converting it back to a DataTable then? I believe, based on some [Googling DataView Sort not working](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/adonet/t52890-dataview-sort-problem.aspx), that sorting the DataView doesn't affect the underlying DataTable.